# Read USB flow in Python - Windows

Tags: python, usb, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need to read data from a barcode reader in Python. The problem is that the barcode reader is usb-connected to the PC which run a software for item sales. So I will need to run a python software in background and read the input from the usb-barcode reader. How can I implement this?

I'm on Windows.

Another idea but I don't think it's possible: could I just simply buy a usb splitter and then connect the barcode-reader to two computers (one with python and the other with the selling software, so the usb signal would be splitted in 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the vendors of the Barcode Scanner (e.g. Zebra) provide an SDK like this one here: https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/products/software/scanning-systems/scanner-drivers-and-utilities/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html

This should be the easiest approach if you find one like this. Some devices also provide a virtual COM port from which you can read the information. You normally can configure format and encoding for the scanners (e.g. data termination etc.).

But to answer your specific question there is a information missing:

- What type of scanner are you using?
- Why do you need to use python?
- Why is the selling terminal distinct from the reading terminal? What purose does each one serve?

Comment: I'm using a scanner called Symbol from Zebra! To answer your questions: I need to use python because I need to create a separate software which will be listen to the scanner while it's used for the selling-terminal. This selling terminal is a closed software which I cannot modify unfortunately. Thanks!!

Comment: So then you can just use https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-linux.html for Linux. Regarding the signal split: it normally depends on what base station you are using what is the best option here.